# Firebase unity callback not calling GameObject.SetActive()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime database to store certain gamemode settings, and to get the settings I use `GetValueAsync().ContinueWith()` it works correctly when I was testing it using `Debug.Log()` but when I needed to show a message to the player by making a message object active it doesn't work properly, that is when debugging the code excecution stops before reaching `GameObject.SetActive()`. This is the code that does what I described.

```
private void GetValue(string path, Action<DataSnapshot> onValueGet)
{
    dbRef.Child(path).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed getting Value Async. {task.Exception}");
        }

        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            onValueGet?.Invoke(task.Result);
        }
    });
}

internal void GetGamemode(string id, Action<Gamemode> onGamemodeGet)
{
    GetValue($"{id}/Settings/Gamemode", (snapshot) =>
    {
        if (int.TryParse(snapshot.ToString(), out int result))
        {
            onGamemodeGet?.Invoke((Gamemode)result);
        }
        else
        {
            onGamemodeGet?.Invoke(Gamemode.Default);
        }
    });
}
```

I call `GetGamemode()` which calls `GetValue()` and if don't get correct data I show a message for the player

```
        FirebaseController.Instance.GetGamemode(id, gamemode =>
        {
            if (gamemode == Gamemode.Default)
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed getting gamemode");
                MessageController.Instance.ShowMessage("Failed getting gamemode... Check game id!", Color.white);
            }
            else
            {
                ShowJoinSelection(gamemode);
            }
        });
```

And I see that through Debug that it calls `ShowMessage()` but it doesn't do anything in the `ShowMessage()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the way I made it work is by waiting for the response in a coroutine and the Invoking the callback after I got the response

```
private IEnumerator GetValue(string path, Action<DataSnapshot> onValueGet)
{
    bool responseGot = false;
    DataSnapshot responsePayload = null;
    dbRef.Child(path).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed getting Value Async. {task.Exception}");
        }

        responseGot = true;
        responsePayload = task.Result;
    });

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => responseGot);
    onValueGet?.Invoke(responsePayload);
}
```

This is the modified method for getting values, and it correctly interacts with `UnityEngine` objects.